# Any workaround for Azure Data Factory not supporting complex ORC type (list, map)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, orc

I am using ADF (Apr 2020) and trying to

- Copy Data from Blob store to SQL Database
- The Blob store (source) have snappy compressed ORC files.
- Few fields in ORC schema are List type.

The "Copy Data" pipelines complains that complex types (List, Map) cannot be handled.

Is this is documented behavior (not supporting complex type in ORC) from ADF? Or, I am doing something wrong.

Is there any preferred workaround?

Comment: Use a [Databricks Notebook task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook) to unpack the complex types prior to insertion into the SQL db.

Answer (score 0):

> Complex data types are not supported (STRUCT, MAP, LIST, UNION).

It is not supported according to the documentation that can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/data-factory/format-orc